# What do students reply to these questions?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

What is a 14yr old supposed to do?

[image: Survey]

Not finding faults or anything, but a 'None of the above' option would be welcome next time...

Answer (score 64):

Questions of the survey are not obligatory. You can leave them unanswered if you feel that you are not qualified to give an honest answer (or you don't want to. right?). So, I expect students (I'm one) to leave those questions empty.

Comment: It would be better if it were made clear that this is possible. Usually in such survey formats you have to answer everything but there's a "n/a" option.

Comment: Wait, it's possible to leave a survey question unanswered?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah it seems that any answer on the SO survey can be skipped but I didn't see that mentioned when I started the survey. I recommend making it much clearer.

Comment: I confess I skipped all the "Write something here" survey questions. Note to future survey creators: I may care enough to take your survey, but I can almost assure you I don't care enough to answer essay questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I seem to recall a line saying "Every question is optional", but that might have just been in the blog post

Answer (score 2):

As Braiam said, you can avoid questions that don't apply to you. However, in your example at least one question is always answerable in theory, even if you don't have a job: you may always have an opinion on whether

> Diversity in the workplace is important

You don't need to actually have a workplace for agreeing/disagreeing to that

Comment: Through, having a framework of reference would allow you to answer it more accurately

Answer (score -19):

I would create a quick script that generates a random (hopefully something that resembles randomness well) integer from 1 to 5 or find one of those random number generators online. Like so:

https://www.random.org/

Once more people do this, we can figure out any patterns in the results or the generator itself.

This of course if the survey is anonymous.

Answer (score -33):

Don't take the survey.

The survey seems to be designed for people that do have a job. Whatever you answer as a student, it will create a false impression.

Creating a post about it on Meta is indeed the best thing you can do, as it makes the creator of this survey aware of the survey's flaw.

This survey should have started with one simple question: *Are you currently employed?*. The questions after that would depend on your answer, and thus there would be two surveys, which will provide a much more accurate conclusion.

Comment: But that's horrible. We, teenagers, still program. Stop assuming that our entire world revolves around jobs, it involves about creating real, live unicorns.

Comment: So if you stumble upon a survey of your bra, do you complain that you don't have a bra? No, you simply do not do the survey!

Comment: @Zizouz212 Virtual high five!

Comment: @Zizouz212 You are not the target market of Stack Exchange's actual customers, for whose benefit the survey is being conducted. It's true that you shouldn't be presented with irrelevant questions, but there's essentially no reason for them to include any questions for students: advertisers don't care. (I guess an issue is giving the impression that the survey is much more than just market research.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks Here I thought the survey was more about Stack Overflow and not the advertisers.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter That makes me feel... Rather uncomfortable.

Comment: @JeremyBanks That's a good reason, but wouldn't allowing students to take that survey actually make the data inaccurate? Even if there were slightly separate surveys, that would improve the accuracy of the data received, would it not?

Comment: Can student program? Yes. Does student counts as developer? a) Nope yet  b) Somewhat already. Stack Overflow **Developer** Survey? a) Skip b) Provide truthful/trustful info (e.g. only say truth about what is relevant to you).

Comment: @Sinatr What? Students can just as easily be developers, just as they are programmers. The word "developer" simply denotes the job - I "develop" programs, so wouldn't I be a "developer" as well? I also contribute to open source projects and the like, and so on